Insert multiple tabs (or characters) using Regular Expressions
I'm using Notepad++ RegEx Replace to convert a lateral list
Q, N, S, G
into a vertical one, with multiple tabs preceding each character.
          Q
          N
          S
          G          

Is there a cleaner way to repeat the multiple tabs I'm inserting instead of the way I'm doing it?
Search: ,\s
Replace: \r\n\t\t
I've tried: \r\n\t{2} but that gives me           {2}Q

What do you mean by "cleaner"? The first line? Try (,\s)|^ and replace with (?{1}\r\n:)\t\t

"Quantifiers cannot be used in the replacement pattern, nor the information how many chars they match."

What I meant was to use a multiplier for the 't rather than manually entering each iteration, especially when replacing with 5, 10, or more tabs. I'm reviewing the referenced question... it's a bit advanced for me but I'll get it eventually.

Whatever you call them. Not supported. What you need to see in the linked post answer is the first sentence (see the second comment here.)
